# How to use Igraph with clusters and Dataframe

Tags: r, graph, cluster-analysis, igraph

I want to plot a graph with the `igraph` package.
I have a Dataframe with the output of the `Kmeans` algorithm with my data and the clusters. And I want this Dataframe to be the input of my graph in order to plot it.

How should i do it?

The format of my Dataframe is the next one:

```
Column1   : Product_Id
Column2-90: ProductCategory (0 or 1 if this product matches or not this category)
Column91  : Cluster: (1-20)
```

Comment: In what way is this a graph?  What are the vertices and what are the edges?

Comment: The vertices are the Product_Id, and the edges i wnat to be the distance between one Product_ID and another